# Is there a function to return all single letter colors in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I learnt of [matplotlib.pyplot.colors](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colors) that the basic built-in colors can be represented as a single letter.

- b: blue
- g: green
- r: red
- c: cyan
- m: magenta
- y: yellow
- k: black
- w: white

Is there a function in Matplotlib to return those colors?

Comment: why do you want this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built in colors are available via [`matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors)

```
>>> print(matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors)
{u'b': (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
 u'c': (0.0, 0.75, 0.75),
 u'g': (0.0, 0.5, 0.0),
 u'k': (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 u'm': (0.75, 0, 0.75),
 u'r': (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 u'w': (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
 u'y': (0.75, 0.75, 0)}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the @Andy's answer returns all available colors with varying color names.

You can use the following to get single color letters only:

```
 >>> [x for x in matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.colors.keys() if len(x)==1]
```